# Can I run Navigatrix in ubuntu

Tags: navigation

Can I run NAVIGATRIX 4 or 5  in Ubuntu or with it. And how would I get there, I'm just trying to learn ,what you can and can't do with Ubuntu Thanks Brian

Answer (score 0):

Navigatrix is an OS, so to use it with Ubuntu I recommend you install it as virtual machine using [VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads)